# Python subprocess terminates with incomplete stdout

Tags: python, process

I've been having problems the following python script code snippet.

```
  p = subprocess.Popen([cmd,classname],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  (stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
```

The length of stdout is supposed to be a fixed 7850, but I've kept getting a      length(somewhere around 100) far less than that. Could someone please explain what the problem is?

Comment: Is the command terminating properly?

Comment: My guess is the problem is in the subprocess. Code doesn't give enough clues.

Comment: Are you calling `sys.stdout.flush()` in the subprocess after you're done `print`ing?

Comment: Flushing shouldn't be required - `communicate()` waits until the subprocess terminates, which should perform an implicit flush. I agree that the most likely issue is in the subprocess code, however.

Comment: I have a program that uses subprocess to read the file content and some files are getting cut / not fully shown. I must use git subprocess as I'm reading content from bare repo. So this is very interesting question for me as well